# How to get variables from another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I have two controllers: job and home

now job counts the number of stopped jobs and at which location like below

```
public void Stopped()
    {

        int HBAStop = db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" && x.LocationID == 1).Count();
        int CRStop =  db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" && x.LocationID == 2).Count();
        int MAStop =  db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" && x.LocationID == 3).Count();
        int QCStop =  db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" && x.LocationID == 4).Count();
        int LTStop =  db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" && x.LocationID == 5).Count();
        int PTStop =  db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" && x.LocationID == 6).Count();
        int SPStop =  db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" && x.LocationID == 7).Count();

    }
```

i then want in the home controller to initialise the job controller and grab the individual variables from the stopped() method, like below

```
 ViewBag.HBAStopped = j.Stopped();
```

how do i add the HBAStop variable to the viewbag? i can get around all this by making them into return methods each but this equals to about 30 methods and seems a bit overkill and untidy. I tried various ways with no success, with the return methods being the only option at the moment

i can provide further information if needed, thank you

Comment: you need to get counts again on other controller `db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" && x.LocationID == 1).Count()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the only difference between each of the stopped counts is the `LocationID`. In this case you could just make a single method to handle them all:

```
public int GetStoppedCount(int locationId)
{
     return db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" 
            && x.LocationID == locationId).Count();
}
```

You could then do:

```
ViewBag.HBAStopped = GetStoppedCount(1);
```

etc...

Just a side note, I wouldn't rely too much on magic numbers e.g

```
db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" && x.LocationID == 1).Count();
```

Where the `1` is a bit ambigious. Prefer enums or static constants e.g:

```
public static class LocationConstants
{
     public const int HBAStop = 1;
     public const int CRStop = 2;

     // etc...
}
```

You can then do:

```
ViewBag.HBAStopped = GetStoppedCount(LocationConstants.HBAStop);
```

Which is much more readable.

Comment: @ataravati Can you explain how it doesn't answer the question? The OP has just stated that it does.

Comment: Sorry! The question was not clear. I though the OP didn't know how to call that function from the other controller.

Comment: Ah, no worries in that case :)

Comment: Thanks for the additional information @DGibbs, can i ask where you would place the locationConstants? in the home or job controller? im just trying to go by best practice, im still getting to grips with it all and prefer to know all the best ways

Comment: I wouldn't place it in either of those. It should be entirely separate. In our projects we usually have a `Constants` class with these as subclasses so `Constants.Location.HBAStop` for example

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, thank you again @DGibbs, really great to know this stuff

Answer (score 0):

//1. create struct:

```
  struct JobStops
{
    int HBAStop;
    int CRStop;
    int MAStop;
    int QCStop;
    int LTStop;
    int PTStop;
    int SPStop;

 }
```

//2- update your method like this:

```
public JobStops Stopped()
    {
        JobStops _jobstops ;
        _jobstops. HBAStop = db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" && x.LocationID == 1).Count();
        _jobstops. CRStop =  db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" && x.LocationID == 2).Count();
        _jobstops. MAStop =  db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" && x.LocationID == 3).Count();
        _jobstops. QCStop =  db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" && x.LocationID == 4).Count();
        _jobstops. LTStop =  db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" && x.LocationID == 5).Count();
        _jobstops. PTStop =  db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" && x.LocationID == 6).Count();
        _jobstops. SPStop =  db.Jobs.Where(x => x.Status == "Stopped" && x.LocationID == 7).Count();
    return _jobstops;
```

}

//3-  ViewBag.HBAStopped = j.Stopped();